# How to handle storage limitations when fetching data from a large data store?

Tags: mysql, algorithm, caching

I am going to be fetching a large amount of data from a data store with a slow internet connection. After fetching the data I have to parse the csv file, fix the errors and store the results in a db. I don't need to keep this data forever. It will only be needed when we need to create reports based on this data. But keeping it in the system means a faster response and we don't have to parse/clean/fix errors in csv files each time. The problem is that our system has much smaller storage space. So I cant keep all the parsed/clean data on our system. At some point I have to delete this data and when a request for this data comes again then we have to fetch, parse and clean it again. I want to have policy for deleting old data. When do I delete the cleaned data? Can somebody give a suggestion for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are describing a classic caching problem where you have a large but slow storage medium and a small but fast storage medium that can't hold all the data.

Ideally, you throw out the data which either won't be used much in the future.  However, it is often hard to predict future access patterns.  So people use heuristics to make informed guesses.

One heuristic is *least recently used*.  This assumes that if I haven't used a data item recently, I won't use it much in the future.  To do this you throw out the data which has the oldest access time.

Another method is to throw out the data that has been least frequently used.

For further information you can look at articles on browser caching, and OS disk caching.